# AngularJS authentication service using Satellizer and Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel, authentication, jwt, satellizer

I'm experimenting with Angular, trying to setup a Angular frontend powered by a laravel backend (REST API). For authentication i want to use json web tokens. For Angular i'm using Satellizer (https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) and for Laravel JWT (https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth).

At the moment, i already can login with AngularJS using correct credentials stored in Laravel. The user info and token is stored in localStorage.

I would like to implement some kind of Angular service that can check if the user is authenticated in order to protect states form ui-router. I already tried a few tuts but i'm unable te get it working. Can someone point me in the right direction? Would be awesome!

**loginController (Angular)**

```
.controller('loginCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$rootScope',
    'utils',
    '$auth',
    '$location',
    'SweetAlert',
    function ($scope,$rootScope,utils, $auth, $location, SweetAlert) {


        $scope.login = function() {

            var credentials = {
                email:      $scope.email,
                password:   $scope.password
            };

            $auth.login(credentials)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var user = JSON.stringify(response.data.user);
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', user);
                    $location.path('/restricted.dashboard');
                })
                .catch(function (response) {
                    SweetAlert.swal("Inloggen mislukt.", "Controleer je email adres en wachtwood en probeer opnieuw.", "warning");
                    console.log("LOGIN NOT OK" + response);
                });
        };
```

**app.states.js (ui-router, Angular)**

```
.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        // Use $urlRouterProvider to configure any redirects (when) and invalid urls (otherwise).
        $urlRouterProvider
            .when('/dashboard', '/')
            .otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider
            .state("error.404", {
                url: "/404",
                templateUrl: 'app/componentsOld/pages/error_404View.html'
            })
            .state("error.500", {
                url: "/500",
                templateUrl: 'app/componentsOld/pages/error_500View.html'
            })

            // -- LOGIN PAGE --
            .state("login", {
                url: "/login",
                templateUrl: 'app/components/auth/loginView.html',
                controller: 'loginCtrl',
                resolve: {

                    deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                            'lazy_uikit',
                            'lazy_iCheck',
                            'app/components/auth/loginController.js',
                            'sweetAlert'
                        ]);
                    }]
                }
            })


            // -- RESTRICTED --
            .state("restricted", {

                abstract: true,
                url: "",
                views: {
                    'main_header': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/shared/header/headerView.html',
                        controller: 'main_headerCtrl'
                    },
                    'main_sidebar': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/shared/main_sidebar/main_sidebarView.html',
                        controller: 'main_sidebarCtrl'
                    },
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/views/restricted.html'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {

                    deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                            'lazy_uikit',
                            'lazy_selectizeJS',
                            'lazy_switchery',
                            'lazy_prismJS',
                            'lazy_autosize',
                            'lazy_iCheck',
                            'lazy_themes',
                            'lazy_style_switcher',
                            'sweetAlert'
                        ]);
                    }]
                }
            })
```

**app.js (Angular)**

```
....
// Satellizer configuration that specifies which API
// route the JWT should be retrieved from
$authProvider.loginUrl = 'zz/zz/laravel/public/api/authenticate';

// Redirect to the auth state if any other states
// are requested other than users
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/auth');
....
```

**Laravel authenticateController (Laravel 5.2)**

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }
    $user = Auth::user();
    //$user->company;
    //$street = $user->company->street;
    // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT

    return response()->json([
        "token" => $token,
        "user" => $user
    ]);

}
```

What i would like to accomplish is creating a laravel Middleware for Angular so that we can check if a user is authenticated and in the future he or she has the right user role to load a Angular state.

Thanks for taking time for my issue. I'm looking forward to see how you would handle this :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution somewhere on SO a while ago and it suits my needs(cant provide original answer yet, credits to the original answer). Event hough I use $routeProvider, I think you can apply similar logic with $stateProvider

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/awesomeRoute', {
            templateUrl: 'views/view.tpl.html',
            controller: 'someAwesomeCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'someCtrl',
            resolve : {
                  //This function is injected with the AuthService where you'll put your authentication logic
                  'auth' : function(AuthService){
                      return AuthService.authenticate();
                  }


                 }
              })
        })
```

The Auth service:

```
 .factory('AuthService', function($q, Service, $window, $location){
          return {
              authenticate : function(){
                  //Authentication logic here, some service to check 
against backend if token you provided is valid and/or you are authorized to enter those sections of application, 
or in your case with satellizer you can use `$auth.isAuthenticated()` method.

                    Service.isTokenValid(_yourToken).then( (res) => {
                      if(res.data === true){
                        return true;
                      } else {
                        return $q.reject('Not Authenticated');
                      }
                    }, (err) => {
                      $location.path('/');
                        return $q.reject('Not Authenticated');
                    })
                  } else {
                    return $q.reject('Not Authenticated');
                  }
              }
          };
      })
```

and finally the "route error catcher", when there is something wrong, return home or to /auth route

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location){
    //If the route change failed due to authentication error, redirect them out
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, current, previous, rejection){
        if(rejection === 'Not Authenticated'){
            $location.path('/');
        }
    });
  })
```